# App is crash, if API data size 500kb and large in react-native

Tags: react-native

**Description::**

I'm working on react-native application. If my API data size is more than 500 kb and can be extended to mb value. My Android/IOS app crashes on loading a page for a second time.

I can not add a pagination to the API, because I want all the data on the page load. I am having only 5 records, but each record having huge data. Pagination not resolved this issue for me. Each record containing 1 year schedule for a record.

**Error Log::**

```
2019-03-22 10:00:31.048 557-557/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/15420/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-22 10:00:31.137 557-557/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error opening /proc/13901/oom_score_adj; errno=2
2019-03-22 10:00:31.140 557-557/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error opening /proc/13901/oom_score_adj; errno=2
2019-03-22 10:00:32.076 1656-1796/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=199, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
2019-03-22 10:00:32.125 467-2617/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
2019-03-22 10:00:32.280 2033-2033/? E/QcDataStatusNotification Service: mobile_data3
2019-03-22 10:00:32.337 2033-2033/? E/QcDataStatusNotification Service: mobile_data9
2019-03-22 10:00:32.357 2033-2033/? E/QcDataStatusNotification Service: mobile_data9
2019-03-22 10:00:32.406 14683-14683/? E/ReflectUtils: Exception e: miui.reflect.NoSuchMethodException: Couldn't find method android/app/ActivityManagerProxy.setProcessForeground(IZ)Landroid/os/IBinder;
2019-03-22 10:00:32.460 14683-14683/? E/MarketManager: String array resource ID #0x0
2019-03-22 10:00:32.461 14683-14683/? E/MarketManager: String array resource ID #0x0
2019-03-22 10:00:32.494 14683-14683/? E/MarketManager: String array resource ID #0x0
2019-03-22 10:00:32.495 14683-14683/? E/MarketManager: String array resource ID #0x0
2019-03-22 10:00:32.513 14683-14683/? E/MarketManager: String array resource ID #0x0
2019-03-22 10:00:32.527 14683-14683/? E/MarketManager: String array resource ID #0x0
2019-03-22 10:00:32.528 14683-14683/? E/MarketManager: String array resource ID #0x0
2019-03-22 10:00:32.599 16143-16184/? E/WakePathManager: UpdateWakePathTask.doInBackground: isWifiNetwork==false
2019-03-22 10:00:32.600 14683-16187/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.xiaomi.mihomemanager.whitelistProvider
2019-03-22 10:00:32.910 14683-14683/? E/HAL: PATH3 /odm/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
2019-03-22 10:00:32.910 14683-14683/? E/HAL: PATH2 /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
2019-03-22 10:00:32.911 14683-14683/? E/HAL: PATH1 /system/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
2019-03-22 10:00:32.911 14683-14683/? E/HAL: PATH3 /odm/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
2019-03-22 10:00:32.911 14683-14683/? E/HAL: PATH2 /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
2019-03-22 10:00:32.911 14683-14683/? E/HAL: PATH1 /system/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
2019-03-22 10:00:33.168 14683-16228/? E/ResourceLoader: fail to get getPathForLanguage: den480/quietImage.png
2019-03-22 10:00:33.168 14683-16228/? E/ResourceLoader: fail to get getPathForLanguage: quietImage.png
2019-03-22 10:00:33.169 14683-16228/? E/ResourceManager: fail to load image: quietImage.png
2019-03-22 10:00:33.169 14683-16228/? E/ResourceLoader: fail to get getPathForLanguage: den480/startImage.png
2019-03-22 10:00:33.169 14683-16228/? E/ResourceLoader: fail to get getPathForLanguage: startImage.png
2019-03-22 10:00:33.169 14683-16228/? E/ResourceManager: fail to load image: startImage.png
```

Some time it's working fine, if API data is too small. This is a problem when API data is too large. Please suggest If anyone having a solution?

Comment: Sometimes you might not need all the data, but statistics from the data, e.g. total no from a year, or highlighted items from that year, to display to user in the first screen. Once user want more details of a record, you can fetch more data from API. Optimal solution would be provide more API methods which return **exactly what the current screen needs, and get more when user interacts**. That is the common solution.

Comment: We need a all data at page load.

Comment: You need to provide more info. How are you fetching the data? It would better if you add your fetch method and sample response from the server.

Comment: https://s.nimbusweb.me/share/2679238/vkbv66hc1fh1gcrzfkn3